# How to wire ceiling fan in old house wiring?

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling-fan

[image]I’m trying to install a Hunter ceiling fan (remote controlled) in my old house( not sure how old) in the living room. There are 2 separate light switches(1 on each side of the room) that control the light fixture there now. There are several wires with no copper wires except for the one connected to the electrical box (bottom right of picture). I do have 1 red wire in the mist of wiring. I have a fan brace kit ready to replace the electrical box. I’m running in the issue that there are 2 incoming wires (power supply, romex?) into one side of the current box (look at right side of picture). The brace kit doesn’t come with both wires coming in on one side. How would I go about completing this job or will I need to hire an electrician? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The wires can come in from any side of the box but you'll need connectors similar to the one shown below. You'll need to shut off the power to the switches and box and disconnect all the wires so you can replace the box with your fan rated box. Mark or tape the wires with different colors so you know exactly how to reconnect them after you install the new box. You've got a lot of wires in there and with changing out the box it might be beyond your skill set. Choose wisely on whether you want to tackle this or not. It's even more difficult working up on a ladder.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying!

Comment: @Jonathan, if you'll take the [tour], you'll note that the appropriate way to say "thanks" is to click the up vote button next to _every_ answer that was helpful to you, then to click the check mark next to the answer that helped you the _most__.